# ZF2 Subdomain routing for language

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, subdomain

For my application I want to make use of subdomains to set a language e.g.:
 - site.com (english)
 - de.site.com (german)
 - nl.site.com (dutch)

I set the subdomain config as follow:

```
'home' => array(
           'type' => 'hostname',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => ':lang.site.:tld',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Application',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                        'lang'       => 'en',
                    ),
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'lang'     => '(|nl|de)',
                        'tld'      => '(localhost|com)',
                    ),
                ),
```

The problem I am facing is when I just want to navigate the english version (site.com)
without a subdomain but I run into 'page not found', I thought I ..'route' => ':lang.site.:tld'.. as '[:lang].site.:tld' but this seems not to work.

Anyone? :)

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Comment: You could check out SlmLocale with its host strategy (https://github.com/juriansluiman/SlmLocale/blob/master/docs/2.Strategies.md#host-name). It has several advantages not to perform i18n in routes, and SlmLocale solves that. It only hasn't the option to skip the locale part in the host strategy when you have the default locale selected...

Answer (score 0):

My bet is that you have a dot after the `:lang` param and that won't allow for url's like `site.com` pass (`.site.com` might). So I made `:lang` optional -- that should, when empty, fallback to default `en` value.
I've also didn't see any reason for `:tld` param to exist, so I threw it out. It's my guess that you didn't need it in the first place, because of url examples you provided.

```
   'home' => array(
        'type' => 'hostname',
        'options' => array(
        'route' => '[:lang][.]site.com', 
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Application',
                'action'     => 'index',
                'lang'       => 'en',
             ),
             'constraints' => array(
                 'lang'     => '(en|nl|de)',
             ),
    ),
```

I've also thrown in `en` to your alternatives just for integrity's sake, that doesn't affect the match, as constraints should only be checked when there's a parameter value present.

I didn't have time to test it, but I think it should work if my understanding of ZF2 routing is correct.